# Error on installing Titan DB on Windows

Tags: hadoop, groovy, cassandra, titan, gremlin

Following the official guide of Titan DB [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/getting-started.html), and trying to run the command:

```
graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')
```

I got this error:

```
Backend shorthand unknown: conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties
```

Obviously, the reason is the incorrect path to the

> titan-cassandra-es.properties

file. So I changed it to:

```
graph = TitanFactory.open('../conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')
```

and got this error:

```
Encountered unregistered class ID: 141.
```

The error happens in the following version: 
titan-0.5.4-hadoop2

On titan-1.0.0-hadoop2 instead of this error message I get this one:

```
Invalid import definition: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.MapReduceIndexManagement'; reason: startup failed: script14747941661821834264593.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.MapReduceIndexManagement  @ line 1, column 1.    import com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.MapReduceIndexManagement    ^

1 error
```

And on titan-1.0.0-hadoop2 I get this one:

```
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Does anyone know how to handle this issue?

Comment: You can pull the `gremlin.bat` and `gremlin-server.bat` from https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/tree/titan11/titan-dist/src/assembly/static/bin -- these latest files should at least correct the error "The input line is too long."

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have not even managed to get `Titan 1` to start up yet.

I do not believe `Titan 1` has been deployed to support Windows out of the box. I.e. the downloadable package will not just work with windows.

Saying that I have managed to get Titan DB 1 to work on windows. To do so, all you have to do is install Cassandra 2.x on Windows. [This](http://www.datastax.com/2012/01/getting-started-with-apache-cassandra-on-windows-the-easy-way) guide may help you out. Start cassandra and enable thrift connections.

With that done you should be able to get Titan doing basic operations on windows. From there you may find dealing with you current errors easier.

**Side Note:** Windows support for `Titan 0.5.x` may be more substantial. So you could look into that as well.